# How to remove "." from number or number/string with two "."

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to remove a "." character from a number or string with two "." characters.

For example

The number 1359.300.00 will be converted to 1359300.00

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Comment: because it is a floating number?

Comment: 1359.300.00 isn't a number, so I guess you have a string, so you can use `replace` like you already suggested

Comment: @Adelin: And you find out if it's possible, by trying it

Comment: What other scenarios do you want to handle? Is `13.59.300.00` also posssible?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all dots except the last, you can do something like this:

```js
function onlyLastDecimal(string, token) {
       /* Requires STRING not contain TOKEN */
       var parts = string.split(token);
       return parts.slice(0,-1).join('') + token + parts.slice(-1)
}

console.log(onlyLastDecimal('123.123.123.123','.'));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `replace()` function for it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">1359.300.00</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(".","");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what if value is `300.00`?

Comment: op should define the scenarios

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya: Yeah so maybe you should wait for clarification from the OP before trying to answer, because the current question is very poorly defined and unclear